# What is the generic term for a thing you subscribe to?

Tags: terminology, programming

I'm trying to set up a naming convention for some software I'm working on, and I need a name for the thing that people subscribe to. In my model we have:

- Subscriber (a person)
- Subscription (the 'link' between the person and the thing being subscribed to.
- ??? (The thing that the person has subscribed to).

In this case, ??? needs to be some generic name. I'm currently using 'Series', but that's not self-explanatory, and is also somewhat painful (in the software environment I'm using) as the singular and plural is the same.

As an analogy, we might have:

- Employee (the person who is employed)
- Employment (the position/role of the person)
- Employer (the company or person providing the position)

Except that 'employment' is continuous, and I need a discrete term: the subscriber receives a series of individual 'things' as part of their subscription, rather than a recurring payment for a continuous service.

Comment: In the library world, they would be called *serials*, singular *serial*, or *periodical(s)*.

Comment: I have never heard of a **subscriband**, but why not?

Comment: Anything beginning with 'sub' is going to sound off. The act of subscribing is, etymologically speaking writing beneath it, signing it at the bottom, underwriting it, So you want a word for the thing which is above the writing below it. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=subscribe Surscription? Which means it is whatever it would be if no-one subscribed, if you see what I mean. It just is what it is.

Comment: Perhaps simply "Subject"?

Comment: "Serial" or "Periodical" expresses what I'm after - but it seems a bit ... old-fashioned, I guess. 1006a - if you make this an answer, I'll accept it if no one else has any other flashes of brilliance. Thanks!

Comment: A 'periodical' or a 'serial' is what you receive from a *service* that sends you 'a thing' periodically!

Comment: The employment example is something that refers to a single thing, so a closed set of terms makes sense.  A subscription can apply to almost anything.  I'm not aware that there is a universal term that applies to anything that is the subject of a subscription.  Usually, the term used in that place is one that refers to the kind of item in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One normally subscribes to a **Service** - whether that be the provision of a monthly magazine, the the provision of technical support, the provision of access to a particular website, etc..

> [**service**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/service)
>   1.  *[mass noun]* The action of helping or doing work for someone.
>   1.1 *[count noun]* An act of assistance.
>   1.2 Assistance or advice given to customers during and after the sale of goods.

Comment: In my case I want to express that the subscribe receives 'a series of things' via their subscription (rather than something continuous like a service). Sorry - my Employee/Employer analogy probably isn't the best. Thanks anyway - _Service_ would work in a lot of cases, though.

Comment: So...use the plural: services. The term is still applicable.

Comment: Being sent "a series of things" is still a service.  A service does not have to be continuous: it can be a monthly or periodic service; it can be a service provided for a fixed period of time; etc..

Comment: Good point - you're right. I still don't think I can use service in my particular context ... guess I'm going to have to give the thing itself a name (The subscription is to receive a selection of wines every month).

Comment: @Beejamin - If you don't like "service" in your specific context, consider "package".

Comment: Why don't you want to call that a service?  The service is the monthly delivery of a choice of wines.

Comment: I agree that it is a service, but the company (and so the software) also has other services. I'm after something to disambiguate the 'periodic delivery service' from the others.

Comment: @Beejamin Now you've changed the Q.! Anyway, if - as you now say - the software is to be used for other services, then you need a *generic* name for the field, namely "service" and the data contained within that field will differentiate the wine service from the other services.

Answer (score 3):

**Publisher.** It maps nicely to real world subscribers who receive subscriptions to periodicals from publishers.  And the general pattern is known as the *Publish-subscribe pattern*.

Comment: That's not bad, but not quite right, I don't think. I'm familiar with the pub-sub pattern. I feel like the 'Publisher' is the entity that _provides_ (outputs) the thing that you subscribe to - that is, the subscriber and the publisher are the 'people' at each end. In pub-sub terms, I think I'm talking about the 'channel' . Actually... channel could work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it's just **Source**?

Because it's the source of the 'things' which the subscriber receives.